# Navigate using $location and passing a hidden param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using `$location.path("page2")` to navigate to page2. I would like to pass a hidden value to the controller of page2. If I use this:

```
$location.path("page2").search("param", "visible")
```

then the parameter appears in the url. Is it possible to pass a value without the user seeing it in the parameter?

Comment: If it's in the browser already, then the user already has access to it, and there's really not much point in trying to hide it from them.

Comment: The first solution of the issue is to use `resolve` function of `$routeProvider` and inject params into controller.
The second solution is to use `$localStorage` and pass params through browser storage.
The third solution (I think is better than other) is to create own `service` to share data between controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my comment, I think the best way is to share data between controllers through `service`. I've created [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e5rhubm/) to demonstrate how to share data between controllers. This is an example and you can adopt it to your needs.

Comment: thank you for you answer + comment. you did point out some possible solutions, thank you!